# What is optimize way to select database rows?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I'm selecting rows which are matching some given values. In my database that content about 1 million of rows. That take huge time to go through each rows to select which are same as given values. The column I'm search contains collection of sentences. Raw by raw stored sentences collection. I think indexing may not be use for my execution. Is there any proper way to solve this problem?

```
    sb.append("SELECT Cor_Sentence FROM corpus Where ");
             for(int k=0;k<wordList.size();k++){
                 sb.append( " Cor_Sentence like '%" + wordList.get(k) + "%' OR ");
             } 
    sb.append(" 1=0");
    rs2 = dbc.sqlExecute(sb.toString());
```

Above code work properly. Problem is time taken to read each row and out matching rows. What kind of technique can I use?

Comment: @BoristheSpider :) I corrected.Can you help to some clue to solve the problem?

Comment: @BoristheSpider . . . That would be on *your* keyboard.  Keyboard layouts around the world have different placements of the letters:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way of achieving this would be to use REGEX like below:

```
WHERE Cor_Sentence REGEXP 'abc|def|geh|ijk'
```

Comment: skaikh "regexp" mean some standard key word or defined one? Is that above code given like similar to (abc or def or geh or ijk ) something?

Comment: See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) for details.

Answer (score 0):

There are two waysi can think of

1) Apply  Non clustered index on column `Cor_Sentence` . It should definitely help. See the [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQLServer/Index/Createanonclusteredindex.htm)

2) Go for pagination if possible.Say 50 rows at a time

Comment: @M Sach can you give me simple example to create non clustered index? Even yet I didn't have used indexing in my tables. Can you please help me little bit further?

Comment: @M Sach what kind of think use in index? That can't may be ascending or descending or etc I can't use. Because the content is just collection of sentences which are read from web pages. According to after looking at some video tutorial now, I think I can't I use indexing. Am I correct? And also language which contain in database not English. That is Asian language "Sinhala".

Comment: see the example link in post, thought syntax depends on DB vendor. Creating this type of index should definitely help as search will be kind of binary serach

Comment: @M Sach my database has two column. One is auto increment id(primary key) and other is above mentioned 'Cor_Sentence' column. Is that enough to CREATE INDEX i_sentences ON corpus (Cor_Sentence)? And after creating should I search through new indexed column? Anything else to should I do for indexing? My main target is to anyhow select whole rows which contains any of given words.

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL's Full Text Searching facilities.

Add a FULLTEXT index to the column or columns you're searching, then use `MATCH...AGAINST` in boolean mode to find your results.

```
ALTER TABLE corpus ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (Cor_Sentence);
```

I can't give you the Java you'd need, but your query should look like this:

```
SELECT Cor_Sentence FROM corpus WHERE 
    MATCH (Cor_Sentence) AGAINST ('First Second Third' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Where `'First Second Third'` is a space delimited list of words to find. This query will select rows where any of the words in the list appear in the searched column. There are operators that allow you to specify whether certain words must appear, must not appear, etc.

You can do this without a full text index but it will be quite slow.

Note: You MUST use the MyISAM engine to be able to use full text searches.

The MySQL Reference is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html)